# Отображение ячеек таблицы

Tags: javascript, json, angular

Есть таблица, в нее по клику будут записываться события. Сейчас они пустые, там есть только число месяца.
Проблема в отображении ячеек этой таблицы.Что нужно написать, чтобы ячейки отображались?

```
<tbody>
 <tr *ngFor="let week of weeks">
  <td *ngFor="let day of week" class="day-of-month">
   <div class="events">
    <span class="day-number">{{ day | date:'d' }}</span>
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

date: Date;
weeks: Array<Array<Date>>;

constructor( private datePipe: DatePipe, private calendar: CalendarService) 
{}

ngOnInit() {
 this.date = new Date();
}

 transformDate(date) {
  return this.datePipe.transform(date, 'MM-yyyy');
 }

 prevMonth() {
  this.date = new Date(this.date);
  this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() - 1);
 }

 nextMonth() {
  this.date = new Date(this.date);
  this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() +1);
 }

 now() {
  this.date = new Date();
 }
```

calendar.service.ts

```
export class CalendarService {

currentDate: Date;
daysInWeek = 7;
Sun = 0;

constructor() {
  this.currentDate = new Date();
}

setDate(date: Date) {
  this.currentDate = date;
}

getWeeks(): Array<Array<Date>> {
  let date: Date = this.getFrom();
  const endDate = this.getTo();

  const weeks = [];
  while (endDate > date) {
   const week = [];
   for (let i = 1; i <= this.daysInWeek; i++) {
      week.push(date);
      date = new Date(date);
      date.setDate(date.getDate() +1);
   }
   weeks.push(week);
  }

  return weeks;
  }

 prevMonth(): CalendarService {
  this.currentDate = new Date(this.currentDate);
  this.currentDate.setMonth(this.currentDate.getMonth() -1);

  return this;
  }

 nextMonth(): CalendarService {
  this.currentDate = new Date(this.currentDate);
  this.currentDate.setMonth(this.currentDate.getMonth() +1);

  return this;
 }

 today() {
  this.currentDate = new Date();

  return this;
 }

getFrom() {
 const from = new Date(this.currentDate.getFullYear(), 
 this.currentDate.getMonth(), 1);

let day: number;
day = from.getDay();

if (0 === day) from.setDate(-6);
else from.setDate(from.getDate() - (day - 1));

return from;
}

getTo() {
 let lastDay = new Date(this.currentDate.getFullYear(), 
 this.currentDate.getMonth() + 1, 0);

if (this.Sun === lastDay.getDay()) return lastDay;

lastDay = new Date(lastDay.getFullYear(), lastDay.getMonth() + 1, 
(this.daysInWeek - lastDay.getDay()));

return lastDay;
 }
}
```

Comment: ты показал свой шаблон, но никому неизвестно с какими данными ты работаешь, каким образом они грузятся, грузятся ли они вообще и тд. Приведи подробнее пример

Comment: у тебя `weeks` - `undefined`, я не вижу где ты сеттишь значение этого свойства

Comment: пока что просто должна отображаться таблица, она без данных. должно быть еще модальное окно, которое будет сохранять события в этот календарь-таблицу. шаблон взят из моего другого проекта, там грузились данные про представления в театре с сервера

Comment: таблица не "должна" отображаться, `ngFor` не может динамически создать представление в цикле когда на входе получает `undefined` (`weeks`)

Comment: да, я потеряла кусок кода. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте, передается ли в дериктиву *ngFor массив "weeks" и правильный ли у него формат, без вводного массива, ngFor не будет строить ячейки.